# Shell script can not pass file data to shell input

Tags: linux, shell, cat, piping

```
cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t | more
```

Why does it showing nothing? Why isn't it showing

```
     April 2012       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30
```

Comment: `|` connects stdout (1) of the first process with stdin (0) of the second. After redirecting the output to a file, there is no stdout left, so there's nothing to pipe. Also, `cat | cat < file` does not really make sense, it gets two inputs to stdin

Comment: @knittl So do you mean `cat < t ` is not executed at all?

Comment: so, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @PavanManjunath typing **cat < t** (only) gives the calender perfectly

Comment: I bet this will work in bash 4, but not bash 3.  The issue is close to what others have said, but not exactly.  `cat > t` writes stdin to a file and breaks the chain starts with `cal`, but `cat < t` should open the chain again.  The problem is bash 3 can only handle one STDIN; the `<` operator actually means "open the file and write it to STDIN".  So for your version of bash, it is choosing to give the pipe precedence over <.  For later versions, I believe that changes (or perhaps give non-empty input precedence).

Comment: @Mike: not exactly, `<` does not "write it [the file] to stdin"; it tells the shell to open the file and associate it with the entry 0 (stdin) in the file descriptor table.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `cal April 2012` prints what you say you want.

Comment: @knittl agreed; I sacrificed technical precision for conceptual clarity. :)  I suppose describing it in terms of fd0 would have helped understand the *why* of the conflicting STDINs.  It's actually an interesting problem: if you run the second cat using strace `cal April 2012 | cat > t | strace cat < t`, you'll see that in fact it reads the cal text from fd0, and writes the cal text to fd1.  Bash must be shuffling something around.

Comment: @l0b0: I assumed the questioner was trying to learn about bash pipes and input redirection, not to print the calendar for April 2012. :)   If I have erred in my assumption, then Dewsworld, today is April 5th.

Comment: @Mike: the fd0 from pipe or the fd0 from io redirect? ;)

Comment: @knittl: well, it actually reads and writes cal data, so it must be coming from the io redirect.  And the process *thinks* the file descriptors are 0 and 1 (`read(0,"     April 2012 ` and `write(1, "     April 2012`).  But bash is quietly discarding the fifo it writes to. Bash will actually run those commands in parallel and connect their STDIN/STDOUTs using file descriptor trickery, and then try to sort out which fifo should be printed at the end of it all.  `strace -f  bash -c "cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t` for the full joy of watching it all happen. :)

Comment: (apologies to Dewsworld for semi-hijacking this question for our discussion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` (anonymous pipe) connects stdout (`1`) of the first process with stdin (`0`) of the second. After redirecting the output to a file, there is no stdout left, so there's nothing to pipe. Also, `cat | cat < file` does not really make sense, it gets two inputs connected to stdin (at least with bash, redirection comes later and "wins": `echo uiae | cat <somefile` will output the content of somefile)

If you want to display output of a command and, at the same time, write it to the file, use the `tee` binary. It writes to a file, but still writes to stdout

```
cal April 2012 | tee t | more
cat t # content of the above `cal` command
```

Comment: Can you name a command which reads from file and give stdout? (like **tee** writes to file and stdout)

Answer (score 1):

Because that first `cat > t` sends all its output to a *file* called `t`, leaving no more for the pipeline.

If your intent is to send it to a file and through `more` to the terminal, just use:

```
cal April 2012 | tee t | more
```

This `| cat < t` construct is very strange and I'm not even sure if it would work. It's trying to connect two totally *different* things to the standard input of `cat` and certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me if there's no existing file named `t` in the current directory.  I'm using bash on Ubuntu Oneiric.

```
$ cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t | more
 April 2012       
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
 29 30
$ cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t | more
$ rm t
$ cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t | more
 April 2012       
 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14  
 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
 29 30
```

Comment: Should not work (and does not work here – debian squeeze. I can test in ubuntu later)

Comment: If it's trick works for you, can you explain why it happens like this?

Comment: hmm.  if I run `cal April 2012 | cat > t | cat < t | more` over and over, occasionally I get output and occasionally I don't.  GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @orzechowskid I got the same issue. It sometimes works for me, sometimes not! Totally strange!